# Display text over button image with Static Resource

Tags: wpf, xaml

This is my button style:

```
        <Style TargetType="local:Button" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Terminal">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Button}">
                        <Image x:Name="img" Source="{Binding DefaultImage,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, FallbackValue=img/0.png, TargetNullValue=img/0.png}" Stretch="Fill">
                        </Image>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="img" 
                                        Value="{Binding PressedImage,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, FallbackValue=img/1_push.png, TargetNullValue=img/1_push.png}">
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

and my button code is as follows:

```
        <local:Button xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Terminal"  x:Name="btnLine" Grid.Column="1" Content="LINE"
                   DefaultImage="img/line.png" PressedImage="img/line_pushed.png" Click="btnLine_Click">
        </local:Button>
```

The problem is button content is not showing up over the image. I also tried to put `TextBlock` inside of `local:Button` but still no luck. How to show the content of a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined where the text should go anywhere in your template - you've literally just told the button to be just an image.

The button will add the 'content' in the element `<ContentPresenter/>` in the control template.  Its an easy thing to overlook! So you need something like:

```
    <Style TargetType="local:Button" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Terminal">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Button}">
                    <Grid>
                       <Image x:Name="img" Source="{Binding  DefaultImage,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, FallbackValue=img/0.png, TargetNullValue=img/0.png}" Stretch="Fill">
                       </Image>
                       <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="img" 
                                    Value="{Binding PressedImage,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, FallbackValue=img/1_push.png, TargetNullValue=img/1_push.png}">
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```